# To know the hosting Control of a Control

Tags: wpf, controls

I have a custom control, its control template will be looks below.

```
 <Style TargetType="local:CustomButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomButton">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="CtrlBorder">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Name="Tbox"
                                     BorderThickness="1,1,0,1"
                                     Text="{Binding TextBoxText,
                                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                    Mode=TwoWay,
                                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            <Button Width="20"
                                    Background="#FFF0F0F0"
                                    BorderThickness="0,1,1,1"
                                    IsTabStop="False">
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In an event, i got the `Tbox` and i need to get the `CustomButton` with this `Tbox`. 
Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can get throught `TemplatedParent` property of that control.

Answer (score 0):

Custom control will lie in Visual Tree as parent so `FindAncestor` will work here:

```
Text="{Binding TextBoxText,
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                              AncestorType=local:CustomButton},
               Mode=TwoWay,
               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```